# sh: time command not found

Tags: bash, time, sh, llvm

In llvm 3.0 test-suite, I am getting the following error on bash:

```
sh: time command not found
```

The code is:

```
if [ "x$RHOST" = x ] ; then
  ( sh -c "$ULIMITCMD $TIMEIT -p sh -c '$COMMAND >$OUTFILE 2>&1 < $INFILE; echo exit \$?'" ) 2>&1 \
| awk -- '\
BEGIN     { cpu = 0.0; }
/^user/   { cpu += $2; print; }
!/^user/  { print; }
END       { printf("program %f\n", cpu); }' > $OUTFILE.time
```

where `$TIMEIT = time`.

I tried to change `sh -c` to `eval` but the error continued.

While trying to solve this error, I noticed something funny that may or may not help solving this:

Running `sh -c "time"` works but `sh -c "time -p"` doesn't.

Do any of you guys have any idea why this error happens and how would I solve it?

Comment: Check `man time` and see if your implementation of `time` lacks the `-p` flag. That said, even if the flag was the problem, the error should then be `-p: command not found` not `time not found`. All that said, are you sure your system's `sh` is pointing to `bash`? If you're on some operating systems, it may be `dash`. (Again, not sure that helps unless `dash` lacks a `time` built-in **and** you have no separate `time` command.)

Comment: "`sh: time command not found`" - is that the _exact_ error message? Also, what output does `readlink -f "$(which sh)"` generate for you?

Comment: The "exact" error is: sh: time: command not found

Comment: readlink -f "$(which sh)" outputs /bin/bash

Comment: Check man time and see if your implementation of time lacks the -p flag. -> Using time -p works normally. The problem is when executed together with sh -c. eval "time - p" works though normally. But in the context of the script I'm executing it seems to not work (gives the error that the time command was not found)

Answer (score 14):

`time` is a reserved word in shells. To use the actual command, try:

```
command time [options] [command]
```

or:

```
/usr/bin/time [options] [command]
```

**Source:**

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/86193/command-not-found-when-trying-to-set-a-format-for-the-time-command/86196#86196

Comment: The program is provided by 'time' package: `apt-get install time`

Comment: If you are on gentoo and receive this error, you will want `sys-process/time`

Answer (score 1):

The program is provided by `time` package.
Install it, for example, like so:

```
apt-get install time
```

This answer enshrines the comment by *jonhattan*.

**NOTE:**

I found this fix useful when I was using GitHub Actions with a script that used `time -p`. So I did this in the `yml` file:

```yml
      - name: Install other packages
        run: |
          apt-get update
          
          # `time -p` is used for benchmarking tests.
          # This fixes error: 'sh: 1: time: not found':
          apt-get install time
      - name: Set up test database and run tests
        run: |
          script_with_time.sh
```